# How to Improve For Loop Performance

Tags: java

This code is pretty fast but I would like to make it faster without using HashMap.

I have a list of Accounts and I am currently looping them to check if `account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)`

Is there a way to improve this using Java 8?

```
public Account getAccountFromCustomer(String customerID, String accountNumber) {
    List<Account> accounts = getAccountsFromCustomer(customerID);
    for(Account account : accounts) {
        if(account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)) {
            return account;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: "I would like to make it faster without using HashMap." Why would you use a HashMap?

Comment: `without using HashMap`, where are you using `HashMap`?

Comment: `getAccountsFromCustomer` what's the implementation of it?

Comment: Yes, you can re-write this with Streams, but it won't be faster, since you still have to iterate over the elements until you find a match.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: How fast is it and how fast would you like it to be? This seems like it's as fast as it could get, unless `accounts` is *very* large or if `getAccountsFromCustomer` takes a while to execute

Comment: I only know that HashMap is a dicionary and it's faster than using Lists

Comment: The only way you could make it faster is by making the `getAccountsFromCustomer` method use the `accountNumber` method to cut down the number of things it returns; for example, if you're reading from an indexed DB table.

Comment: If `accounts` is very large, try out `parallelStream`.  It also depends on `getAccountsFromCustomer` method.

Comment: İf you want performance in for loop you can implement binary-search algorithm. Considering your data is in order.

Comment: Exactly why shouldn't you use `HashMap` to improve performance? Also, why not override `getAccountsFromCustomer` to also take an `accountNumber`? This seems like an overly complicated filter for a method that should be refactored.

Comment: `getAccountsFromCustomer(customerId).stream().filter(a -> a.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)).findFirst().orElse(null)`. It won't have better performance.

Comment: @AndyTurner How will it make it faster?  It's more readable, but not necessarily faster.

Comment: It *might* be faster if `getAccountsFromCustomer` returned a `HashMap<Integer, Account>` where the key is the `account.getAccountNumber()` (only possible if that's unique), but this depends if it's faster to create a `List` or `HashMap` inside `getAccountsFromCustomer`. (also this uses HashMap which you don't want, but I can't think of any other way).

Comment: @Sid "It won't have better performance".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I understood the question wrong but there is a performance improvement if I use `parallel`:

```
@Test
public void testIt(){
    Integer accountNumberLookingFor = 50001;

    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000; i++){
        accounts.add(new Account(i));
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    accounts.stream().filter(account -> account.accountNumber.equals(accountNumberLookingFor)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    System.out.println("Time of execution in milliseconds:" + stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));


    stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    accounts.stream().parallel().filter(account -> account.accountNumber.equals(accountNumberLookingFor)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    System.out.println("Time of execution in milliseconds:" + stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

}

private class Account{
    Integer accountNumber;

    private Account(Integer accountNumber){
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Account number: ".concat(String.valueOf(accountNumber));
    }

}
```

leads to:

```
Time of execution in milliseconds without parallel:50  
Time of execution in milliseconds with parallel:9
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantages usign this? Why isn't everyone using that parallel stuff?

Comment: Using `parallel` here will use the [default thread pool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool), shared by the entire application. So you might get contention - and actually be slower - if there are other things also using the default thread pool.

Comment: @Tiago "Why isn't everyone using that parallel stuff" you should perhaps read *Effective Java 3rd Ed* which has a lot to say about why it's not something you should choose by default.

Comment: @AndyTurner In my dockerized application I dont care about that. The thread pool is only reservated for my service

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the classes, used in this example, but from an algorithm point of view, it looks like your are doing the following:

```
// Create an unordered list.
getAccountsFromCustomer();
// Run through it
for(Account account : accounts) {
  if matches()...
}
```

The speed of this algorithm is `O(n)`.

If you put the results in an ordered list, you might use a binary search. You'll need a `O(n*log n)` algorithm to create that list (not just adding account names at the end of the list, but inserting in an alphabetical ordered way), and afterards you use a binary search for finding the account name within that list (performance `O(log n)`.

Obviously, you'll need two separate functions for that:

- One function which creates the list (this function is called only once).
- One function for finding the account number (this function is called every time you need to find the account, based on its account number).